# How to keep my web services awake in nodejs to run forever though i am using forever npm module?

Tags: mysql, node.js, web-services, forever

I am using rabbitmq,mongodb and mysql with my webservices.
To keep my webservices awake i am using npm forever module(forever start app.js).

```
warn:    --minUptime not set. Defaulting to: 1000ms
warn:    --spinSleepTime not set. Your script will exit if it does not stay up for at least 1000ms
info:    Forever processing file: app.js
```

But my web services goes down after a certain period probably after 9-12 hours of started.
If i restart my web services using node app or forever start app.js,my web services are again doing good and goes down again after certain span and this cycle goes on.
Is there any possible way to fix this and also I would like to know the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you write the console log and error log to a file and check if you have any errors which is killing the node process.

```
forever start -o logs/out.log -e logs/err.log app.js
```

This might help troubleshoot exceptions and handle them.

Comment: ohhh great but where the log file will get created?

Comment: Create a logs directory inside your app folder, forever will write the logs there.

Comment: This is the content present in my error log forever file til now.

(node:20336) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 logged listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:20336) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit

Comment: Check if you have bugs in your code or increase the maximum listeners limit. 
    emitter.setMaxListeners(n)

Comment: How can i increase the maximum listeners limit. emitter.setMaxListeners(n)?